# Join Table with 2 Field related to one field

Tags: mysql, join

I face some problems here and i need any helps

this is my table

TableA

```
uomid      | uomname
1            KG
2            Gram
```

TableB

```
id         | itemname      | uomid1   | uomid2
1            Corn            1          2
```

What i hope for result is

```
id         | itemname      | uomname1 | uomname2
1            Corn            KG         Gram
```

Thanks for any helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join TableA twice with different alias names.

```
SELECT B.id,B.itemname,A1.uomname as uomname1,A2.uomname as uomname2
FROM TableB B JOIN
     TableA A1 ON A1.uomid=B.uomid1 JOIN
     TableA A2 ON A2.uomid=B.uomid2
```

**Result:**

```
ID  ITEMNAME    UOMNAME1    UOMNAME2
------------------------------------
1   Corn        KG          Gram
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/347e39/1).